# creating javadoc with ant for only the dependent classes of a given class (java file)

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I want to create javadoc with ant from a java source file and just from the dependent classes of this file. These are in a java project, but i don't need javadoc from all the java files.
Is there a way to create javadoc like javac

```
javac includes="package/Java_source.java" destdir="dir/classes"
```

that compiles the source files and just the dependent classes? If there isn't, then is there another way?

Thanks, Tamas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can add a fileset and / or a packageset parameter:

Example with a fileset:

```
<javadoc
    destdir="docs/api"
    author="true"
    version="true"
    use="true"
    windowtitle="Test API">

    <fileset dir="src">
      <include name="foo/bar/BaseClass.java"/>
      <include name="foo/bar/baz/DependentClassA.java"/>
      <include name="foo/bar/phleem/DependentClassB.java"/>
    </filset>

</javadoc>
```

But you will have to figure out the dependent classes yourself, I'm afraid.

**Reference:**

- [Ant javadoc Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html)

---

There is no way to find out what the "dependent classes" are without starting the job. The only thing I can think of is a brutal hack:

On the compiled classes, use a byte code analysis tool like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and check all classes in the code base for their usage of your given class (source code analyis is not enough because of possible wildcard imports and same-package usage). From the List of used classes, build a list of source files, and pass that to the Javadoc task (probably best to create an Ant task that does all this). But this is heavy stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but I have at least 200 source files. I'm looking for another way, that automatically collects the depending classes.